# A textbook question on the Perron solution

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the question:

> Let $D$ be the annulus $\{a<|z|<b\}$. Find $\tilde{h}(z)$ for the function $h(\zeta)$ defined by $h(\zeta)=\alpha$ for $|\zeta|=a$ and $h(\zeta)=\beta$ for $|\zeta|=b$. Here $\tilde{h}(z)$ is defined to Perron solution to the Dirichlet problem corresponding to the boundary function $h(\zeta)$.

By hint, I know I should use the comparison function $A+B\log|z|$ and obtain its coefficients. But that's just an easy answer. Should I also prove that the Perron solution is unique, such that once we solve the values of $A$ and $B$, that is our Perron solution for sure? If that's the case, how should I do it?

Comment: Fitting the coefficients $A$ and $B$ to the data will indeed give you a solution iof the Dirichlet problem. Uniqueness then is a general fact about solutions of the Dirichlet problem.